# NAudio. Microphone data to decibels

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I use NAudio library in order to get data from microphone and I was successfull in doing so.
Now I want to calculate this data into decibels.

```
value = 20* Math.Log10(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue);
```

Is this a proper way of calculating it?

Comment: You formula need to values.  Decibels is a reference between two values (not one) which is a relative measurement.  If you want an absolute value then you want dbm which uses a standard value for the reference.  NAudio library which is just reading voltage values from you  microphone and you would need to calibrate the value against a standard.

Comment: @jdweng So for example. If I want dBu value all I need to do is:
`value=20*Math.Log10`
`(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue/0.775)`;
Vo - for dBu is 0.775
Is that correct?
Also I have a question. 
I assume that 
`device.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[] are Peak Values` of the signal.
But:
`device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue` is RMS value?

Comment: 0.775 is rms so you need to compare apples with apples.  Once you get the rms you can then do a comparison of rms to peak using db. How can a peak be an rms?  The meter is giving peak so you do not clip and loose quality.  Clipping with loose high frequency output.